# Laravel view in a directory, not found

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel 5, views are locate to `ressources/views/<view>`.
I want to do something like `ressources/views/<directory>/<views>`, putting views in another level of directory (because I have a lot of them, and I want to store them in parts).
I created dorectories, then changed the Controller return, to something like `return view('directory1/view1');`, but view1 is not found.
It might be on the controller side that I need to correct something, but I don't really know...

Answer (score 5):

Lets say you have a blade template in `resources/views/directory1/view1.blade.php`

and you want to access **view1.blade.php**

then in controller you just need to write

```
return view('directory1.view1);
```

If you have another blade template in `resources/views/directory1/sub_directory1/view1.blade.php`

then you need to write

```
return view('directory1.sub_directory1.view1');
```

Comment: Interesting that it works if i write `return view('directory1.template1');` (note that template1 is the template of view1), but writing `return view('directory1.view1');` (trying to access the view) doesn't work. I can access the template, but not the view. I get something like `View [template1] not found.` (with the name of the templates.

Comment: If you don't understand then please give us your blade file structure. So that we can give you a better understanding of it.

Comment: There it is: `ressouces/views/directory1/view1` for view1, and `ressouces/views/directory1/template1` for the template (the view and its template are sibling files)... That's why I don't understand why the empty template can be display on the site, with no data, because it's the template, and the view cannot because of black magic ^^

Comment: which 1 is your blade file among these 2. By dafult laravel think the file name as view1.blade

Comment: then there should be no issue to access. there might be any other issue (typo). May be some name issue or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

use it as

```
 directory.inner_directory.view_name
```

I have created `event` directory and it has a file `homepage.blade.php` so I would call it as

```
return view('event.homepage', $dataArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i learnt about templates, and how a view extends from a templates.
`@extends('template1')` isn't a "relative" path, from what I expected, it search for the template at the root view directory (`ressources/views/`), so i had to write `@extends('directory1/template1')` instead... now it can find the templates, that is next to my view file.
It confused me when i found out, because i though at the first place that the view file would search relatively to its own place, but that's not the case. ^^